# Git push keeps prompting username and password

Tags: git, github, git-bash

Having problem where I git push origin master and it prompts username and password.

I was on same git repo using laptop, it doesn't prompt username and password but when I use it on my desktop it prompts username and password.

Also I have been cloning using https on laptop and it doesn't prompt me username and password when I push it.

Comment: That's probably because on that machine, your git-config is not set. Can you provide your git config?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see this link to cache the credentials:
[Caching your GitHub password in Git](https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/)

Comment: This fixed it. I did this earlier and it kept prompting me for username and password.  Must have been typo on my part.